# How to move data into multiple Rust closures?

Tags: rust, gtk-rs

I have a two widgets in a simple GTK app:

```
extern crate gdk;
extern crate gtk;

use super::desktop_entry::DesktopEntry;

use gdk::enums::key;
use gtk::prelude::*;

pub fn launch_ui(_desktop_entries: Vec<DesktopEntry>) {
    gtk::init().unwrap();

    let builder = gtk::Builder::new_from_string(include_str!("interface.glade"));

    let window: gtk::Window = builder.get_object("main_window").unwrap();
    let search_entry: gtk::SearchEntry = builder.get_object("search_entry").unwrap();
    let list_box: gtk::ListBox = builder.get_object("list_box").unwrap();

    window.show_all();

    search_entry.connect_search_changed(move |_se| {
        let _a = list_box.get_selected_rows();
    });

    window.connect_key_press_event(move |_, key| {
        match key.get_keyval() {
            key::Down => {
                list_box.unselect_all();
            }
            _ => {}
        }
        gtk::Inhibit(false)
    });

    gtk::main();
}
```

I need to change `list_box` from both events. I have two closures that `move`, but it is not possible to move `list_box` to both closures simultaneously as I get the error:

```
error[E0382]: capture of moved value: `list_box`
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 9):

As explained in Shepmaster's answer, you can only move a value out of a variable once, and the compiler will prevent you from doing it a second time.  I'll try to add a bit of specific context for this use case.  Most of this is from my memory of having used GTK from C ages ago, and a few bits I just looked up in the gtk-rs documentation, so I'm sure I got some details wrong, but I think the general gist is accurate.

Let's first take a look at why you need to move the value into the closures in the first place.  The methods you call on `list_box` inside both closures take `self` by reference, so you don't actually consume the list box in the closures.  This means it would be perfectly valid to define the two closures without the `move` specifiers – you only need read-only references to `list_box`, you are allowed to have more than one read-only reference at once, and `list_box` lives at least as long as the closures.

However, while you are allowed to *define* the two closures without moving `list_box` into them, you can't pass the closures defined this way to gtk-rs: all functions connecting event handlers only accept "static" functions, e.g.

```
fn connect_search_changed<F: Fn(&Self) + 'static>(
    &self, 
    f: F
) -> SignalHandlerId
```

The type `F` of the handler has the trait bound `Fn(&Self) + 'static`, which means that the closure either can't hold any references at all, or all references it holds must have static lifetime.  If we don't move `list_box` into the closure, the closure will hold a non-static reference to it.  So we need to get rid of the reference before being able to use the function as an event handler.

Why does gtk-rs impose this limitation?  The reason is that gtk-rs is a wrapper around a set of C libraries, and a pointer to the callback is eventually passed on to the underlying `glib` library.  Since C does not have any concept of lifetimes, the only way to do this safely is to require that there aren't any references that may become invalid.

We have now established that our closures can't hold any references.  We still need to access `list_box` from the closures, so what are our options?  If you only have a single closure, using `move` does the trick – by moving `list_box` into the closure, the closure becomes its owner.  However, we have seen that this doesn't work for more than one closure, because we can only move `list_box` once.  We need to find a way to have *multiple* owners for it, and the Rust standard library provides such a way: the reference-counting pointers `Rc` and `Arc`.  The former is used for values that are only accessed from the current thread, while the latter is safe to move to other threads.

If I remember correctly, glib executes all event handlers in the main thread, and the trait bounds for the closure reflect this: the closure isn't required to be `Send` or `Sync`, so we should be able to make do with `Rc`.  Morevoer, we only need read access to `list_box` in the closures, so we don't need `RefCell` or `Mutex` for interior mutability in this case.  In summary, all you need is probably this:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
let list_box: gtk::ListBox = builder.get_object("list_box").unwrap();
let list_box_1 = Rc::new(list_box);
let list_box_2 = list_box_1.clone();
```

Now you have two "owned" pointers to the same list box, and these pointers can be moved into the two closures.

Disclaimer: I couldn't really test any of this, since your example code isn't self-contained.

Comment: "the closure either can't hold any references at all, or all references it holds must have static lifetime" - took days for me to figure this out. This should be written in big, bold writing on any documentation to do with multi-threading as by default they're always `'static`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use cloning on the gtk-rs widgets.

In gtk-rs every object implementing `gtk::Widget` (so basically every GTK object you can use inside a `gtk::Window`) must also implement the `Clone` trait. Calling `clone()` is very cheap because it's just a pointer copy and a reference counter update.

Knowing this below is valid and cheap:

```
let list_box_clone = list_box.clone();
search_entry.connect_search_changed(move |_se| {
    let _a = list_box.get_selected_rows();
});
```

But since this solution is verbose and gets very ugly very soon if you have more than one objects to move, the community came up with the following macro:

```
macro_rules! clone {
    (@param _) => ( _ );
    (@param $x:ident) => ( $x );
    ($($n:ident),+ => move || $body:expr) => (
        {
            $( let $n = $n.clone(); )+
            move || $body
        }
    );
    ($($n:ident),+ => move |$($p:tt),+| $body:expr) => (
        {
            $( let $n = $n.clone(); )+
            move |$(clone!(@param $p),)+| $body
        }
    );
}
```

The usage is very simple:

```
search_entry.connect_search_changed(clone!(list_box => move |_se| {
    let _a = list_box.get_selected_rows();
}));
```

This macro is capable of cloning any number of objects that are moved into a closure.

For further explanation and examples check out this tutorial from the gtk-rs team: [Callbacks and closures](https://gtk-rs.org/docs-src/tutorial/closures)

Comment: This whole issue (OP & Replies) was very helpful to me.  I ran into a similar issue as the OP this past weekend but ended up putting all of my logic requiring a move into just 1 button click function.  I am sure I will be using this clone gtk-rs idea in the future.  Thank you for posting!

Answer (score 3):

You literally cannot do this. I encourage you to go back and re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/) to refresh yourself on ownership. When a non-`Copy` type is *moved*, it's gone — this is a giant reason that Rust even exists: to track this so the programmer doesn't have to.

If a type is `Copy`, the compiler will automatically make the copy for you. If a type is `Clone`, then you must invoke the clone explicitly.

You will need to change to [shared ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html) and most likely [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/).

Shared ownership allows a single piece of data to be jointly owned by multiple values, creating additional owners via cloning.

Interior mutability is needed because Rust disallows multiple mutable references to one item at the same time.

Wrap your `list_box` in a `Mutex` and then an `Arc` (`Arc<Mutex<T>>`). Clone the `Arc` for each handler and move that clone into the handler. You can then lock the `list_box` and make whatever changes you need.

See also:

- [What is the right way to share a reference between closures if the value outlives the closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41506075/155423)
- [How to share an Arc in multiple closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31360003/155423)