# Can't move value in mutually exclusive `Entry` API methods

Tags: rust

I want to do as follows, but `columns` is moved in both `and_modify` and `or_insert` (which we know are mutually exclusive), but the compiler will not allow it. Is there a way to still use the `Entry` API, or should I refactor to something like `match self.tables.get(&table_name)`, which the compiler will understand are mutually exclusive branches?

```
self.tables.entry(table_name)
           .and_modify(|e| e.columns = Some(columns))
           .or_insert(TableInfo{
               policies: None,
               columns: Some(columns),
           });
```

Comment: Please modify your code to contain a [mre]? It's easier for people to answer when the code is complete.

Comment: Related: [How to move data into multiple Rust closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52464653/3650362)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `or_insert()` returns a mutable reference to the value – either the existing one or the newly inserted one – you should be able to insert `None` for `columns` in the new entry, and then unconditionally overwrite it with `Some(columns)`:

```
self.tables
    .entry(table_name)
    .or_insert(TableInfo {
        policies: None,
        columns: None,
    })
    .columns = Some(columns);
```

A different, somewhat more generic solution is to wrap `columns` in an `Option` first, and then use `Option::take()` in the two mutually exclusive closures:

```
let mut columns = Some(columns);
self.tables
    .entry(table_name)
    .and_modify(|t| t.columns = columns.take())
    .or_insert_with(|| TableInfo {
        policy: None,
        columns: columns.take(),
    });
```

Only one of the two closures will actually be able to extract the original value, but we know that exactly one will be executed, so this is fine. (I replaced `or_insert()` with `or_insert_with()`, so we actually have two closures, only one of which is executed. This isn't strictly necessary to make this approach work but I think it makes it clearer.)

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8d86c4e26b3b1e06ea31fda58ca7782a